# Is it safe to inject context into a eventlet thread like this?

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, eventlet

I need to inject thread level context information for logging and debugging purposes. I've been told that this is potentially unsafe.

```
greenthread = worker_pool.spawn(run_worker, args, handle_result)
# this logging_context attribute will be accessed by the logging library
greenthread.__dict__['logging_context'] = 'data for logging'
greenthread.link()
```

While certainly not something you would want to do often, it was the only way I could set a thread local global constant, which the logger could access.

This can then be accessed later by the logger via

```
eventlet.getcurrent().logging_context
```

As far as my knowledge in python goes, I don't see how this is unsafe, why do others say this is potentially a recipe for disaster?

---

While I see it as a rather ugly monkey patch, I am not creating global mutable state. I am creating a thread-local constant that is instantiated before the thread is even run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, "safe/unsafe" is for obsessed parents. As programmers we can define expectancy for troubles in a much more strict and useful way.

- That approach works now, so while eventlet and greenlet versions are locked, it will work and everything is great.
- You're changing Greenthread attributes after `spawn`. Right now it takes `sleep()` or other way to yield to "event loop" before newly spawned greenthread executes, but that behavior may change in future. Which means that `run_worker` may already be running. You can use `eventlet.pools.Pool()` to manage proper setup and link of greenthreads before allowing them to run.
- In future it may break because greenthread would get `__slots__` to save memory, or particular `__setattr__` implementation for other reasons.
- There is tested and supported API for what you're doing, it's called thread local storage. You use it like regular Python threadlocal object, but use patched version of `threading`[1].
- You may like Logbook[2] more, it has cleaner way to do the same (using threadlocal under the hood).

Sample code for `threadlocal` route:

```
def add_logging_context(context, fun, *a, **kw):
  tl = threading.local()
  tl.logging_context = context
  return fun(*a, **kw)

pool.spawn(add_logging_context, 'data for logging', run_worker, args, handle_result)
```

[1] http://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html

[2] https://logbook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thank you for the information, most informative. However I don't know about the efficacy of threading.local as it must be set within the thread, I was using this approach as it allowed me to set it outside the thread, before it ran.

Comment: I've added sample code that should be used for both threading.local and thread attribute ways to ensure order of setup/run events. Also added comment how your code doesn't explicitly specify that order (`greenthread.context = ...` after `spawn()`).